# position: fixed - issue in IE6.

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, position

I have searched many articles, that ie6 could not support position:fixed, and maybe set position:absolute and top position. But I tried many times can not work well. Can anyone help me to modify my code?( the effection is that my code show in ie8)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
html, body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#fff;}
#headerwarp{width:100%;height:78px;margin:0;padding:0;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:10;}
#headertop{width:100%;height:28px;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:blue;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:10;}
#headerbottom{width:100%;height:50px;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:green;position:fixed;left:0;top:28px;z-index:10;}
#footerwarp{width:100%;height:53px;margin:0;padding:0;position:fixed;left:0;bottom:0;z-index:10;}
#footerbottom{width:100%;height:65px;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#000;z-index:10;}
#localcontent{width:100%;margin:0;padding:78px 0 105px 0;top:0;}
#content1{position:fixed;width:100%;height:20px;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#ff0;z-index:10;top:78px;}
#content2{position:fixed;width:100%;height:25px;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#f00;z-index:10;top:98px;}
.box{width:100%;position:relative;top:45px;padding:0;margin:0;}
.slide {margin:10px;}
.sl{width:100%;}
li{margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
ul li,li{width:400px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
.contenttop{height:25px;position:fixed;z-index:10;top:123px;padding:0;margin:0;width:290px;background-color:#0FF;}
.contentbottom{width:400px;float:left;padding:0;margin:0;height:1000px;}
.col1, .col2, .col3{float:left;padding:0;margin:0 3px 0 3px;}
.pcol1, .ptcol1{float:left;margin:0 0 6px 0;}
.ptcol1{text-align:center;font-size:14px;color:#222;font-weight:bold;padding:0;position:fixed;z-index:10;top:148px;background:#f00;}
.pcol1{padding:2px;position:relative;top:30px;background:#ff0;}
.col1, .ptcol1{width:139px;}
.pcol1{width:135px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="headerwarp">
 <div id="headertop">
    </div>
    <div id="headerbottom">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="localcontent">
        <div class="box">
         <div id="content1">
            </div>
            <div id="content2">
            </div>
            <div id="sl">
                <ul class="ul" style="z-index:1;">
                    <li class="li">
                     <div class="contenttop">
                          content
                        </div>
                        <div class="contentbottom">
                            <div class="col1">
                             <div class="ptcol1">
                              content1
                                </div>                                
                                <div class="pcol1">
                                111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col1">
                             <div class="ptcol1">
                              content2
                                </div>                                
                                <div class="pcol1">
                                111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="footerwarp">
 <div id="footerbottom">
    </div>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all you need to use a CSS reset. You don't need to declare the same css properties in every element you use. It's insane, thats why you have headaches. Just google for CSS reset and or use Yahoos: (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/). Everything can be done if you know how to recode your work and use workarounds, included positioning in IE6. I'm note the one who will give you an answer to your problem, just an advice...

Comment: Maybe you should mention what you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE 6 vs. position:fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074335/ie-6-vs-positionfixed)

Answer (score 0):

I won't claim it as my own solution because that would be unfair to the person that put so much effort into fixing it, but I believe you might want to look at the website of Stu Nicolls ([CSS Play](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/fixed.html))